# Refresh gridview data with response redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview, asp.net-ajax

The print button in below grid view it opens print page in new tab.

Using this java-script code.

**Java Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetTarget() {
        document.forms[0].target = "_blank";
    }    
</script>
```

Also the print button updates `OrderStatus` from 'Pending' to 'Received'

The problem is when i press the print button in the grid data is not refreshed i have to reload the page to see that `OrderStatus` has been changed to the updated value.

**Behind-Code**

```
protected void gridOrders_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string commandName = e.CommandName.ToString().Trim();
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
        GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
        Int32 rowind = gvRow.RowIndex;
        string orderid = row.Cells[1].Text;

        switch (commandName)
        {

            case "Print":
                if (r.CheckReceiving(orderid))
                {

                Session["orderid"] = orderid;
                Server.Transfer("OrderPrint.aspx"); 

                }

                else
                {
                    string msg = r.AddReceiving(r.GetNextReceivingID(), orderid, DateTime.Now.ToString());
                    if (msg == "true")
                    {
                        o.UpdateOrderStatus(orderid, "Received");
                        gridOrders.DataSource = o.ManageOrders(UtilityClass.ReadFromCookie("login", "OutletD", Request));
                        gridOrders.DataBind();
                        Session["orderid"] = orderid;
                        Server.Transfer("OrderPrint.aspx"); 
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        divreceivedfalse.Visible = true;

                    }
                }


                break;

            default: break;

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);

    }
}
```

**Grid Is Inside UpdatePanel**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridOrders" OnRowDataBound="gridOrders_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="gridOrders_RowCommand" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered  text-nowrap" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Print" ShowHeader="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="SetTarget('_blank');" CommandName="Print" CausesValidation="False" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs" Text=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-default " />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderID" HeaderText="Order #" SortExpression="OrderID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm tt}" HeaderText="Order Date" SortExpression="OrderDate" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" CssClass="label label-primary" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OrderStatus") %>'> CausesValidation="False" Text=''></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case update panel can't understand that there was change in data to update. Therefore you need to update it manually. You can do this by calling

```
UpdatePanelName.Update();
```

in appropriate location like this:

```
if (msg == "true")
{
    o.UpdateOrderStatus(orderid, "Received");
    gridOrders.DataSource = o.ManageOrders(UtilityClass.ReadFromCookie("login", "OutletD", Request));
    gridOrders.DataBind();
    UpdatePanelName.Update();
    Session["orderid"] = orderid;
    Server.Transfer("OrderPrint.aspx"); 
}
```

Notice that you should change `UpdatePanelName` with your own update panels name.

Comment: i still have the issue

Comment: The thing that does not update is your label bound to `OrderStatus`?

Comment: but not only the label all grid data

Comment: Check two more things please. (1) There are a lot of `if`s check if the `Update()` gets called by placing a breakpoint. (2) Make this column a normal `BoundField` to see if the problem is from `TemplateField` that have a binding inside.